# SQL Server CE 2.0 database download

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-5.0

One of our clients requested and application can be installed on windows mobile os 5. We've started development, but the SQL Server CE that is installed on the clients devices is SQL Server CE 2.0.

After some research, it looks like SQL Server CE 2.0 is only supported with .NET Compact Framework v1 which would mean that we need to build a Windows mobile 2003 application. We have the framework, but do not have the database. I've been looking for hours for a download, does anyone know where I can get a copy of SQL Server CE 2.0 and the dev tools to hook it up to vs2005?

Comment: You can use verion 3.5 SP2 and Visual Studio 2008 with WM 5, have you considered this, SQL CE 2.0 is out of support.

Comment: Thank you for all the support.  The client didn't want to upgrade because they thought running both versions on the same device would cause an issue with their legacy program.  We found that both versions of sql ce 2.0 and 2005 can work side by side without issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server CE is EOL. You can use SQL Server CE 2005 (v3.1) and upgrade the existing database:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17439

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F4%2F7%2Fa%2F47a548b9-249e-484c-abd7-29f31282b04d%2FUpgradingSQLServerCE.doc&ei=hd_SUNC0AcXHsgar14CoCA&usg=AFQjCNHz9_tnNcgqoAQIVKT54mv2As_BDA&sig2=9VqZcp0OG3_HtoCRbnJaGQ&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.Yms

BTW: you can also use SQL Server CE 2.0 assemblies with newer Compact Framework versions. It will not only run with CF 1.0 but also with 2.0 and 3.5